# Why are there random characters appearing in my code?

Tags: html, doctype

I create email flyers and for some reason I am getting weird characters appearing near others that aren't numerical or alphabetical. They seem to appear when I come back to the file at a later date, it doesn't happen as soon as I type.

I'm not sure if its something to do with my Doctype because it's the same as I've been doing for the past 2/3 years and I've only noticed this problem now happening over the past month or so.

My Doctype:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

Here is an example of what I mean. These have appeared next to a **£** and a **'**

[image]

Comment: Why don't you use an HTML5 Doctype? `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Comment: Do you have the following in your code:

 `<meta charset="utf-8">` or 

`<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">`?

Comment: @JacquesMarais I'm not a "coder" so it's not something I new I needed. I would just start a new Dreamweaver file and use what it gave me assuming it would be fine. But thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Try giving your documents an HTML5 doctype:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

and specifically declaring a character set of UTF-8:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

**Eg.**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title> ...
```